# How to create a waiting line in coffeescript or javascript ? or another approach

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, coffeescript, faye

**What my app do:**

1. Streams information asynchronously (It's a comet style app and im using Faye).
2. Appending to a carrousel.
3. Displaying it for 7 secs.
4. Repeating the step (2).

**What my problem is:** 
If i append the data to the carrousel right in the moment that arrives it will overwrite the current display (ignoring the 7 secs).

**What i am doing:**
Trying to build a 'waiting line' in coffeescript so when the new data arrives it gets in line and after 7 secs the first element on the line pop it and append. I tried to use setTimeout but it didn't work because it is asych.

**An example:**

```
line = []
# the second parameter is the callback function when a new data arrives
faye.subscribe 'my/channel/', (data) -> 
  appendEl = (el) ->
    $('.my-container').append(el)
    line.slice(0,1)
  line.push(data)
  # I think this could work if timeout could block, like sleep()
  # So when new data arrives it will get in line
  my_time = setTimeout(appendData(data), 7000)
  if line.empty?
    clearTimeout(my_time)
```

I dont know if it is the best approach, this is my first app that streams live data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two things you can do to do something many times with intervals.

- use setTimeout with function, which will call setTimeout for itself
- use setInterval with the function

What about your problem you just need to add some variable in the outer scope and use it, something like

```
var pipe = []

faye.subscribe('my/channel', function(data) {
   pipe.push(data)
})


setTimeout(appendData, 7000)

function appendData() {
   if (pipe.length) {
      var item = pipe.shift()
      $('.my-container').append(...)
   }
}
```